# Insert column into a matrix in OjAlgo - How to do that?

Tags: java, ojalgo

I have an matrix

```
Primitive64Store X
```

And I want to insert a column vector `y`

```
double[] y
```

To a specific column in `X`. How can I do that in OjAlgo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer!

```
X.fillColumn(0, column, Access1D.wrap(y));
```